# How to require() a dependency that doesn't exist yet with Webpack?

Tags: docker, webpack

Thanks for your attention, I've been facing this issue for a couple of days.

I've got a React/Express project from Create React App inside a Docker container.

Basically, I've got some JSON files that I need to get at docker runtime because I don't want to have different docker images, I'd like to have a single one.

When I retrieve the files and then run `npm run build` at docker runtime my code works fine.

But, the problem is that I want to run `npm run build` at docker build time. And my code is not being able to find the JSON files because they were not bundled by webpack.

This is the current way that I'm using to load the files

`` const artifact = require(`./${path.join(config.files.dir, `${file}.json`)}`); ``

How can I load these files after the webpack build?

Currently, I don't have any webpack config files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify: `npm run build` starts the webpack build step and bundles your code, correct? So when you run this during docker build and the JSON files can't be found, they are not there yet, correct? So what exactly is the question? How you can build your frontend without relying on the JSONs and later retrieve them?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue that I'm facing. =)
Thanks for rephrasing, @TN1ck

Comment: Do you want to edit the Webpack config or would your like to avoid that?

Comment: I'll do whatever it takes to solve this issue. If it requires dealing with webpack config I can take it. =)

Comment: @ChristianSaiki The answer would be to host these JSONs somewhere and request them when the app is actually starting. It's afaik not possible to include something else after webpack has been build. Technically there is also not much of a difference between requesting these JSONs on startup or directly bundling them.

Comment: After banging my head a lot with this problem I decided to do exactly what you said. I'm using `fetch` to get these JSONs instead of `require()`. But I still wanna know if there is a possibility of doing some webpack magic in order to solve this issue.